# jQuery - Retrieve a single specific Class, while having multiple

Tags: jquery, css

I'm working on a project with a navigation that is animated. 
(Joomla working in the background)

How can i retrieve the `class="item-##"` only, while having multiple classes (shown below).

My jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var timer;
    var hover;

    $('#nav li').hover(
        function() {
/*Here!>>*/ var id = $(this).attr('class').split('-')[1];
            $('.moduletable-subNav ul').slideUp();
            $('#submenu-'+id).slideDown();
        },
        function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
            timer = setTimeout(function() { $('#submenu-'+id).slideUp(); },1000);
        }
    );

    $('.moduletable-subNav ul').hover(
        function(){
            clearTimeout(timer);
        },
        function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            timer = setTimeout(function() { $('#'+id).slideUp(); },1000);
        }
    );
});
```

My HTML:

```
    <div class="moduletable">
    <ul class="menu" id="nav">
            <li class="item-109 current active parent"><a href="/tenc2012/burgerlijkrecht" >Burgerlijkrecht</a></li>
            <li class="item-110 parent"><a href="/tenc2012/strafrecht" >Strafrecht</a></li>
            <li class="item-108"><a href="/tenc2012/bestuursrecht" >Bestuursrecht</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="moduletable-subNav">
            <ul class="menu" id="submenu-109">
                    <li class="item-114"><a href="/tenc2012/burgerlijkrecht/burgelijk-recht-deel-1" >Burgelijk recht deel 1</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="menu" id="submenu-110">
                    <li class="item-117"><a href="/tenc2012/strafrecht/strafvordering" >Strafvordering</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question - can you explain better what you mean by retrieving a class? Do you mean retrieving an item that has that class? And what do you mean by 'having multiple classes'?

Comment: You should use the `item-blahblah` "identifier" as each LI's *ID*, or just store the number part in the element as a `data` attribute for a simpler implementation.

Comment: Where are the `class-xxx` being added? It would be better to put the identifier in the `id` or `data` attribute to make it easier to retrieve later. Classes are supposed to group elements, not identify them individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One technique that I sometimes use for this is cheating a little and using "rel" or other unused attributes to pass things like this around. Try setting:

```
<li ... rel="109">
```

and then getting:

```
$(this).attr('rel')
```

A bit of a hack, but fairly simple to do.

**EDIT**

Examples using karim79's "data-number" suggestion:

```
<li ... data-number="109">
```

And jQuery:

```
$(this).attr('data-number')
```

Comment: Or the data attribute instead `data-number="109"`(that's what they're there for).

Comment: Ah yes, that would be a lot more standards-compliant.

Comment: `rel` is often misused in HTML when, in fact, it's invalid on most elements.

Comment: Using a template-overwrite in Joomla I got it printed in with an data-number="###". Using that now :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with:

```
var classes = $('li[class^="item-]"').prop('class').split('\s');
var theClass;
$.each(classes, function(){
    if (this.match(/^item-/))
        theClass = this;            
});
```

Comment: +1 yes please, also for OP why so much Jquery for just doing a simple thing bruv innit.

Comment: Lol bruv you got the awesome way already + all of 3 others way up and down. use of `prop` makes it nice.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I follow you, but do you want:

```
$('#nav li[class="item-109"]')
```

If you want the number, I guess you could do a

```
$(this).attr('class').replace(/[^\d]/g, "");
```

Or too be a bit more safe

```
$(this).attr('class').replace(/^.*(item\-\d+)$/, "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var classes = $('#my_element').attr('class').split(" ");

var item_class = $(classes).filter(function(a,i) {
  return i.match(/item\-[0-9]+/);
});

console.log(item_class);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('li').each(function(){
        console.info($(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0]);
    });
});
```